# Two way payment options for UK customer based website?

Tags: ecommerce, paypal, payments, payment-gateway, money

I want customers to be able to pay us through our website but I also want **us** to be able to pay customers using the same payment method. I also want the payment processes to be simple (as possible!) and for payments to incur minimal fees.

I understand that implementing eWallet only payments with operators such as PayPal, Moneybookers, Click'nBuy (any others?) may be the way to go. What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

You want

- a UK based system
- that can receive and send payments
- simple to use
- that requires minimal fees

Your requirements are very high!

PayPal is probably one of the most simple services. It's simple to use, you can receive payments as well send payments with a minimal effort. The problem is that it's not cheap, if I remember correctly they require the 3% of the transaction.

I honestly don't know Moneybookers. You have other alternatives such as [Google Checkout](https://checkout.google.com/) and [Amazon Payments](https://payments.amazon.com/).

But according to your requirements, I believe PayPal can be a reasonable solution, at least to start.

Comment: Thanks. Just to add that it doesn't need to be a UK based system as such - but it needs to be currently used and accepted as a mechanism of online payment by a significant number of people in the UK (like PayPal).